# Absolute element not placing over relative element

Tags: html, css, position

Within my header, I am trying to place `pending-button-notification` over the`images-cart` image. For some reason, the `pending-button-notification` div is showing on the left side of the header div.

Does anyone see why this isn't placing correctly?

This is the problematic code:

```
<div id="pending-order-button">
    <a href="pendingOrders.html"><img src="images/cart.png" class="header-buttons" alt="Car">
        <div id="pending-button-notification"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
#header-wrap {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto 5%;
}
#header-logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.header-buttons {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    margin: 30px 40px 0 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.header-buttons:first-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#pending-order-button {
    position: relative;
}
#pending-button-notification {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #09afdf;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <a href="dashboard.html">Logo</a>
    <img src="images/menu.png" class="header-buttons" alt="Pending Orders">
    <div id="pending-order-button">
      <a href="pendingOrders.html"><img src="images/cart.png" class="header-buttons" alt="Car">
        <div id="pending-button-notification"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Your image is floated right and the positioned is at left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your `float:right` on `.header-buttons` which is causing the problem.

I suggest that you remove that and float the `#pending-order-button` div instead so that it and all it's content is moved to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pending-order-button {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
}
```